# paypal button for react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

so I'm trying to get the paypal button to show up on my app but I can't get it work. I'm basing it off this jsfiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/rbacekkb/

I tried to put into my app but the button isn't showing up on the page that I want. I don't know what i did wrong.

```
paypal.jsx

import React from 'react';



class PayPalButton extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // you can take this value from a config.js module for example.
        this.merchantId = '6XF3MPZBZV6HU';
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let container = this.props.id;
        let merchantId = this.merchantId;
        window.paypalCheckoutReady = function() {
            paypal.checkout.setup(merchantId, {
                locale: 'en_US',
                environment: 'sandbox',
                container: container,
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <a id={this.props.id} href="/checkout" />
        );
    }
}

module.exports = PayPalButton;
```

trying to get it show up in this page currently for testing.

```
home.jsx

import React from "react";
import {Grid,Row,Col,Button,Jumbotron, Carousel, Panel} from "react-bootstrap";
import PayPalButton from "../components/paypal";
import {LinkContainer} from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

const title = (
    <h3>Fashion News</h3>
)

const title2 = (
    <h3>Fashion History</h3>
)

const title3 = (
    <h3>Fashion Items</h3>
)

const Home = React.createClass({
  displayName: "Home page",
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props)
  },
  render(){
    return (

        <PayPalButton id="button" />

    );
  }

});
module.exports = Home;
```

index.html

```
<script>
    (function(){
      var ef = function(){};
      window.console = window.console || {log:ef,warn:ef,error:ef,dir:ef};
    }());
  </script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/3.4.0/es5-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/3.4.0/es5-sham.js"></script>
  <script src="react-with-addons-15.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="react-dom-15.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.38/browser.js"></script>
```

Comment: 1) Don't use IDs in React components! 2) Your anchor is self closing so it doesn't seem to show up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that nobody has yet developed a react's paypal button until today (for react-native, there may be one, but my library is the first), that's why I have just created one for everybody!

==========

For everyone's reference, if you want to use Paypal's express checkout button (simply passing the total amount to be paid)

Please use `react-paypal-express-checkout` (***I'm the author***):

**Install**:

```
npm install --save react-paypal-express-checkout
```

**Simplest Example** (but it will show the Paypal express check out button):

```
import React from 'react';
import PaypalExpressBtn from 'react-paypal-express-checkout';

export default class MyApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const client = {
            sandbox:    'YOUR-SANDBOX-APP-ID',
            production: 'YOUR-PRODUCTION-APP-ID',
        }   
        return (
            <PaypalExpressBtn client={client} currency={'USD'} total={1.00} />
        );
    }
}
```

==========

For more detailed document, please go here:

https://github.com/thinhvo0108/react-paypal-express-checkout

This library was developed for reactjs, written in ES6, simple but yet workable, please check my tutorials for both simplest and full examples

This library provides the Paypal's express check out button (which means we can now just pass in the total amount to be paid)

Later, more advanced features will come!
Fork & pull-request are welcomed, and please also give me credit if you use or find it interesting!

Comment: If anyone is looking for a Stripe alternative in React.js, you checkout this [step by step guide](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-express-stripe-payment/) to setup a minimal Stripe server with Express and using it with a React client application.

Comment: This doesnt work. I followed instructions on https://github.com/thinhvo0108/react-paypal-express-checkout. I see the button but when I click on it....nothing happens. No popup (no issues with popup blocker), no console errors, no logs, no request/response errors.....NOTHING.

Comment: @SujitJoshi have you got your Paypal's App ID? that is important!

Comment: im setting a sandbox id ONLY. Also on further debugging...I found that when the button is clicked....it sends a request with env as 'production' even though it is not set/used.

Comment: I will check the latest version of my library and fix the problem if any, thank you for reporting the issue

Comment: @SujitJoshi or in the mean time, could you please set env={'sandbox'} so that you can play around? Thanks

Comment: @thinhvo0108 I created an issue on ```react-paypal-express-checkout``` github page, would you take a look at it please?

Comment: Is there a way to send product information through this button? I can accept payments but paypal doesn't show what they've ordered using this method.

Comment: i followed the instructions on github.com/thinhvo0108/react-paypal-express-checkout. Unfortunately i can't see any button.

Answer (score 4):

PayPal provides the button implementation for React:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/configure-payments/single-page-app/

It’s a 2 step copy&paste job.
Only change I had to make:

Change

```
const PayPalButton = paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });
```

To

```
const PayPalButton = window.paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });
```

Comment: its not working under next,js any workaround?

`Server Error
ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Comment: Made it worked loaded script with defer in _app.js and then under component level used hook of useEffect in that :


`useEffect(() => {
    if (window.paypal) {
      window.paypal.Buttons().render("#paypal-button-container");
    }
  }, []);`

Button showed up! #nextjs

Answer (score 3):

PayPal actually exposes a React button:

https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/frameworks.md
https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/demo/react.htm

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Yes, actually Paypal exposed one for reactjs, but there's no clear document and example. It was a bit more difficult for me to create another true react-paypal-express-checkout library, please check my answer above